# JQuery does not recognize Glyphs in var

Tags: jquery, glyph

I have a form with a JQuery validation in the input tag I have some glyphs.
If the input field is selected only the default value must disappear.

Here is the complete code:

HTML:

```
<input name="naam" id="naam" defaultVal="U bent ge&iuml;ntresseerd in * :" value="U bent ge&iuml;ntresseerd in * :" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').ready(function(){     
$('input, textarea').focus(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).val();

    if (inputValue  == "Naam * :" || inputValue == "Voorletters * :" || inputValue  == "Telefoon * :" || inputValue == "E-mail adres * :" || inputValue == "Uw inruil auto * :" || inputValue   == "Kilometerstand * :" || inputValue   == "Kenteken van uw auto * :" || inputValue == "U bent geïntresseerd in * :"){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});

$('input').blur(function(){     
    var newInput = $(this).val();

    if (newInput  == '' || newInput == ' '){
        $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));

        var idName = $(this).attr('id');

        if(idName=="naam" || idName=="voorletters" || idName=="tel"  || idName=="email" || idName=="intresse" || idName=="inruilauto"  || idName=="km" || idName=="kenteken"){
            $('#'+idName).addClass("error");
        }
    }else{
        var idName = $(this).attr('id');

        if(idName=="naam" || idName=="voorletters" || idName=="tel" || idName=="intresse" || idName=="inruilauto"  || idName=="km" || idName=="kenteken"){
            $('#'+idName).removeClass("error");
            $('#'+idName).addClass("good");
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Well, what value does `inputValue` have when you e.g. `alert()` it?

Comment: show more jquery code because I have not recognize what is `this` and `inputvalue`.

Comment: Are you trying to make placeholder? There is attribute for it.

Comment: @Broken ohh that Unicode character in your screen name is *lovely*.

Comment: Here is the complete code, the alert doesn't seem work when I select the input box with the glyhp.

Comment: I solved it, instead of emptying the input by checking the input value i empty the input by cheching the id.